# How to get the groups of a user in Active Directory in .net 6 blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to get the list of AD groups a user belongs to, but for some strange reason ClaimsIdentity brings back all the user's information except the groups they belong to.

When I try to implement solutions from previous .NET versions it tells me that these libraries are deprecated.

Code Example:

```
var claims = ClaimsIdentity.Claims.Where(q => q.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid).Select(q => q.Value);

        foreach (var claim in claims)
        {
            var name = new SecurityIdentifier(claim).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
        }
```

This returns me the clients entity but when I explore the result I don't receive the group tag, what am I doing wrong?